# Application Settings: How to persist between app versions?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, application-settings

I use the `Application Setting` to store some settings to my portable app, but one thing that I notice is that everytime when I compile a new version with a new version number set in the assembly file, all my settings resets, returning to the default value.

Searching in the AppData folder, I've found the folder with then name of my app with more folders inside, contaning the .xml with the custom settings.

Q: How can I continue using the settings from the last version in the new one? (Without having to Ctrl+X-Ctrl-V the old settings to the folder of the new release)

Comment: Correct, should I delete or let this question linked to that one?